# Add up timespans in list

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying the get the average time spent on a task.
Any idea on how to add up a list of timespans(minutes). here is an example of my code

```
For Each row As DataRow In rows

      Dim current As TimeSpan = CType(row("started"), 
                    DateTime).Subtract(row("Ended"))
      OrderList1.Add(current)
Next
Dim Averagetime As TimeSpan = OrderList1.Add(OrderList1)/Orderlist1.count
```

Comment: iterate `OrderList` to accumumlate total minutes before you divide

Comment: It's usual to do endtime-starttime to avoid negative durations, but I suppose your timespans may be arranged such that your order makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Averagetime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(OrderList1.Sum(Function(x) x.TotalMinutes) / Orderlist1.count)
```

end btw. I think you have to use `CType` on `row("Ended")` as well:

```
  Dim current As TimeSpan = CType(row("started"), 
                DateTime).Subtract(CType(row("Ended"), DateTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Dim query = from row in theTable.AsEnumerable()
            select (CType(row("started"), DateTime).Subtract(row("Ended"))).Ticks
Dim averageTime As TimeSpan = new TimeSpan(query.Average())
```